# CSS transform: rotate() causes ugly font rendering

Tags: css, css-transforms

Both on Chrome and Firefox the rotated text has strange width and spacing anomalies on the vertical strokes (that are now horizontal).
CSS is:

```
font-family: arial;
transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

On Chrome and Firefox:

[image: on Chrome]
[image: on Firefox]

The see also on [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/penmightier/pen/JZGGER).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That behavior without the vertical blurred?

Comment: I would just like it to look like the horizontal version, rotated.

Comment: Well that's the only way to do it

Comment: My point is that the quality is very bad. Look at the thickness variation in the vertical lines, and the letter spacing.